# What Android versions have captive wifi detection?

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

A *captive Wi-Fi* or *captive portal* being a Wi-Fi network that redirects all websites to a page, usually with a form to log in, enter a code, or accept some T&Cs.

My [samsung-nexus-10](/questions/tagged/samsung-nexus-10) can detect when I've connected to a network with this behaviour, and brings up a [notification](/questions/tagged/notification) to tell me, but my old [htc-desire](/questions/tagged/htc-desire) can't. When was this feature introduced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As best as I can tell on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiWatchdogStateMachine.java?av=f), functionality relating to walled gardens (captive portals) was added to `WifiWatchdogStateMachine.java` in 4.0.1. I can't find it listed in the [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) to confirm exactly when it was added, but that would seem to match with your Nexus 10 having the feature but not your HTC Desire.

Comment: My HTC Wildfire S has this notification on 2.3.5...